# How can I programmatically prevent tasks rename and deletion on Project Server 2019 in Project Web Access?

Tags: development, sharepoint-on-prem, project-server

How can I programmatically prevent tasks rename and deletion on Project Server 2019 in Project Web Access (`/PWA/Project%20Detail%20Pages/Schedule.aspx?ProjUid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&ret=0`)?

I have three solutions for these purposes:

- Project Professional Add-in
- Project server local event handler and
- Custom web service

But I can't prevent tasks rename and deletion on Project Server 2019 in Project Web Access. When I use this technic (`https://sharepointprojectserver.com/project-online-jsom-event-handler-for-save-publish-any-other-buttons/`) I can only log button clicks, but can't prevent it.

Something like:

```
_grid = projectDrilldownComponent.get_GridSatellite().GetJsGridControlInstance();
_grid.AttachEvent(SP.JsGrid.EventType.**BeforeTaskDelete**...
```

OR

Something like this in Project Professional add-in:

```
private void Application_ProjectBeforeTaskDelete(Task tsk, ref bool Cancel)
private void Application_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(Task tsk, PjField Field, object NewVal, ref bool Cancel)
```

OR maybe I can do it in local Project Server event handler?

Comment: Using event handlers with an add-in should work. See [How do I listen for a Project Change event from an MS Project VSTO Add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686672/how-do-i-listen-for-a-project-change-event-from-an-ms-project-vsto-add-in).